# Hashtag is removed from URL, how to find what part of script(s) make it happen?

Tags: javascript, url

I notice that on a site where I have a hashtag parameter at the end of the URL, if the parameter has a . in it such as:

```
www.mysite.com/whatever/#myparameter.my
```

After some scripts load, the # is removed from the URL:

```
www.mysite.com/whatever/myparameter.my
```

I'm trying to step through debugger to find the script that changes this but having a hard time, any recommendations on how I can find the script code that changes this?

I've done some searching for `location.hash` and overall `document.location` but there's lots of scripts to look through and these returns tons of results. Any help would be appreciated, I cannot disclose the site or provide a URL.

Comment: probably those scripts change the hash.
you need to comment one by one, to see which one truncates the hash.

Comment: search for pushState.

Comment: @KevinB wow dude thanks a ton, I found it by searching for pushState and then stepping through the code. Looks like some custom script was indeed doing `.replace` on the hashtag with nothing. Never will understand why people down vote legit questions.

Comment: I downvoted it because your title doesn't remotely match what you are asking for in your question. You don't want to catch when it is happening, you want to know how it is being done, and/or what is doing it.

Comment: @KevinB I see thanks for the explanation, probably defeats the point, but I'll adjust the title, didn't think about how `catch` has it's own meaning with JS. I was thinking in layman's terms like "find it before it occurs = catch". Anyway, really appreciate that you did leave me a clue for help that really did help!

Comment: I have the same issue.  I want to watch the url for changes. so far the unload event does not capture it...